# passport-azure-ad unable to validate `id_token` due to wrong KID

Tags: javascript, node.js, openid-connect, passport-azure-ad

I'm encountering an issue when using the `passport-azure-ad` library where the library throws an error when trying to validate the `id_token`. The specific error message is `"authentication failed due to: In _validateResponse: failed to generate PEM key due to: a key with kid %s cannot be found"`

I can see that the `kid` in the `id_token`'s header is a value which does not appear in the keys discovery endpoint (of the format `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/discovery/v2.0/keys`).

Is there any reason why this might happen? I'm unable to figure it out.

My code is the following:

```
passport.use(
  new OIDCStrategy({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    identityMetadata: IDENTITY_METADATA_URL,
    redirectUrl: SUCCESS_REDIRECT_URI,
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    responseType: 'code',
    scope: 'email profile',

    loggingLevel: 'info',
    loggingNoPII: false
  })
)

app.get(
  '/oauthv2/login',
  passport.authenticate(
    'azuread-openidconnect',
    { failureRedirect: '/fail' },
    (req, res) => {
      // ...
    }
  )
)

app.post(
  '/oauthv2/success',
  passport.authenticate(
    'azuread-openidconnect',
    { failureRedirect: '/' },
    (req, res) => {
      // ...
    }
  )
)
```

From the `pazzport-azure-ad` logs I can see the following steps are carried out before the error occurs:

- received id_token
- received access_token
- received refresh_token
- token decoded
- working on key
- working on key
- working on key
- authentication failed due to: In _validateResponse: failed to generate PEM key due to: a key with kid %s cannot be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that I had created a v1 App in Azure Active Directory, although this was not clear ANYWHERE and the `id_token` said it was `ver: 2.0` but it wasn't....

If you want a v2.0 app in Azure AD you cannot create it from the `Enterprise Applications` section, you have to use the `App registrations (Preview)` section.

This solved my issue and the `id_token` contained a valid KID after I deleted my app and recreated it correctly.

Hope this helps anyone who encounters the same problem!

Useful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

If anyone from Azure reads this, please know that adding `(Preview)` in the title of any section means that I will automatically not click it because it seems like it's not something important. However, in this case it was the ONLY way to create a v2.0 app!